# How to read numerical cells without converting to scientific notation (reading excel using Apache POI)

Tags: java

[image]I am trying to read an excel file and validate the values.

While reading one of the columns which has decimal values, the digits after the decimal point are not correctly retrieved. Suppose, I am trying to read **-117035791.877483** number but the result I am retrieving is **-1.1703579187748297E8** (which is in exponential format and don't want that format) if I directly read using below method.

```
double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

I also tried converting the same number to decimal first as below code, but it is adding more digits after decimal point like -117035791.87748297.

```
String s = BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
```

I also tried to retrieve value directly as String value but still, the problem persists. Please suggest the way through which I will get Exact value with decimal points from excel.

Comment: That's not exponentially formal that's the scientific notation  for decimal point

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19984096/6793637

Comment: E8 means  valuebefore E * 10 ^ 8

Comment: Which is the number in ur cell ,

Comment: -117035791.877483 is the number which I want to get but not able to retrieve with exact decimal points without scientific notation.

Comment: I made some changes to make it test related (reading data from excel and validating the value)

Answer (score 0):

Tested with all the data you gave:

```
      package runner;


import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src\\files\\test2.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        int row_count = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        System.out.println("no of rows in the data file is:" + (row_count));

        int column_count = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        System.out.println("no of columns in the data file is:" + (column_count));

         DataFormatter dataFormatter = new HSSFDataFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Inside loop


        for (int row_index = 1; row_index < row_count; row_index++) {

            XSSFRow currentrow = sheet.getRow(row_index);

            //Create cell where there will be no data
            currentrow.createCell(6, CellType.STRING);

            //get value of the cell
            String val=currentrow.getCell(0).toString();

            //get address of the cell
            CellAddress add=currentrow.getCell(0).getAddress();

            //set formula on newly created cell to convert the value from the cell to text (=TEXT(A1,"0.00000000000000000000000") 
            currentrow.getCell(6).setCellFormula("TEXT("+add+",\"0.000000000000000000000000000000000000\")");  

            // set formula doesn't trigger the formula, we have to use evaluate cell to apply the formula
            CreationHelper creationHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();
            Cell cell = evaluator.evaluateInCell(currentrow.getCell(6));

            //print the formula
            System.out.println(currentrow.getCell(6).getStringCellValue())  ;

            //close the workbook
            wb.close();
//                  String cellValueStr = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(currentrow.getCell(0) );
    }


    }

}
```

See if this helps

**Note:**

you will have more zeros in decimal as you mention in the formula . So if the formula is TEXT(A1,"0.0") the only one decimal place will be there, for TEXT(A1,"0.000") there will be 3 and so on

and

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

Comment: Thank you for help.Above code works fine for cell value -117035791.877483 but for other values it is adding more decimal points , I guess. For example, cell value -44227642340.6819 , it is reading as -44227642340.68186 so instead of 0.6819 , it is taking 0..68186. Same for -3666272860.55857, it is reading it as -3666272860.5585732 and for -11029273623.5079, reading it as -11029273623.507858.

Comment: @DarshanPatel i updated my answer, see if it works

Comment: Hi, I tried with below code but still some values are not retrieving as expected like in excel value is -65533.333 but when I am reading it is coming as -65533.332999999999.For value -3666272860.55857, it is coming as -3666272860.5585732.

cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
System.out.println(cell.toString());

Comment: @DarshanPatel i updated the answer , see if this helps , i used all the test data you mentioned adn is working fine

Comment: There will be extra 0 but I think there is no way to avoid it. Unless all values have same decimal digits

Comment: Wb is the workbook object

Comment: I have code structure as below. As per your suggestion,I am trying to add portion above code but not getting compilation CellAddress.

Comment: Not able to get CellAddress.Getting compilation on this line. CellAddress add=cell.getAddress();

Comment: @DarshanPatel you have to import

Comment: import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;

Comment: Added the full code

Comment: You have to set formula on a different cell , self reference is not allowed . Please use the way I mentioned

Comment: Create a new cell , set the formula , evaluate formula print the value .. when you evaluate the formula it will represent the value as string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but it's worth a try.  Add an apostrophe to the beggining of the field in excel and see if it picks up the number in the expected format.

Comment: That will work because that makes the Excel field as text . But he want to read numerical cell